# Beamer: Chinese characters cause "Emergency stop"?

Tags: beamer, texstudio

I'm new to both LaTeX and beamer, but I need to create slices mixed with English and Chinese characters. I'm not sure if this is possible but at least I want to have a try.

```
% Compile with xelatex
% UTF-8 encoding

\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

%\usepackage{utopia} %font utopia imported

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{default}

%------------------------------------------------------------
%This block of code defines the information to appear in the
%Title page

\begin{document}
\title[土地] %optional
{融资平台购地、地方政府财务缺口与房地产周期}

\subtitle{——基于土地交易数据的分析}

\author[张路, 朱宏佳，龚刚] % (optional)
{张路\inst{1} \and 朱宏佳\inst{2} \and 龚刚\inst{3}}

\institute[VFU] % (optional)
{
    \inst{1}%
    南开大学经济学院
    \and
    \inst{2}%
    暨南大学
    \and
    \inst{3}%
    云南财经大学金融研究院
}


\date[June 2014] % (optional)
{香樟经济论坛 2016/6/18}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}



%End of title page configuration block
```

It's a immediate imitation of the beamer example on creating a title page, with Chinese character of course. However, When I compile it in texstudio, it cause a "Emergency stop" without further explanation.
Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: can you show the log file you got. Make sure that you used xelatex not pdflatex to process the file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) By the way, it is better appreciated when you post a *complete* [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), instead of just a code snippet. Indeed, reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is, is much easier when we have directly compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. It is tedious, but it is an extra work TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand will not have to do. So they could help you more efficiently!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Yes , I use xelatex instead of the default pdflatex

Comment: The source generated a good title page by using xelatex.

Comment: then please post the log file with the error in a code `{}` section so we can see why it fails for you.

Comment: Thank you, david and ebo, the error has been fixed, I omit the `\begin{document}                                                              \begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments